# How to Export Foreign Key Field to Excel In Django Views.py?

Tags: excel, django-models, export

Getting this Error:- 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'menu_here__starters'

I'm using Django-Excel Lib

In My Models.py

Class Restaurant(models.Model):

```
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  area = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
  menu_here = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
```

Class Menu(models.Model):

```
  starters = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  desserts = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

In my Views.py

def download_excel_4(request):

```
query_set = Restaurant.objects.all() # Foreign column is Menu
column_names = ['menu_here__starters','menu_here__desserts' ]
return excel.make_response_from_query_sets(
        query_set,
        column_names,
        'xls',
         file_name="Restaurant With Complete Menu Database"
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `make_response_from_query_sets` takes the objects returned by `query_set` and displays it along with column names which should correspond with the field names of the objects.

The `column_names` acts like a filter displaying only the field names you want but it cannot further query after the objects are got. Therefore valid names are `['name', 'area', 'menu_here']`.

An alternative would be to get objects as a dict with the related fields while querying using the `.values()` method and then using `excel.make_response_from_records`.

```
query_record = Restaurant.objects.all().values('name', 'area', 'menu_here__starters', 'menu_here__desserts')
return excel.make_response_from_records(
    query_record,
    'xls',
     file_name="Restaurant With Complete Menu Database"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is so simple!